# How to map in Google spreadsheet with regions of a country

Tags: google-sheets, data-visualization

Google Sheet GeoMap chart allows me to create a map with world data. It allows to compare data for different countries but I would like to create a map with data from different regions of France.

How can I do that? I tried to find a way but I didn't find any solution...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. If you look into the Customization tab, you'll see you can zoom in to eg. Europe, but that's it.

You could use github's geojson support if you don't want to run your own web gis or do the visualisation offline. Start here for some docs:
https://help.github.com/articles/mapping-geojson-files-on-github/

Or Google Fusion Tables.

If you don't have the geometries for the regions, look at the GADM.org database.